# How to user openlayers js in alpinejs

Tags: javascript, openlayers, vite, alpine.js

I am trying to get openlayer working in alpine

but i have this error which i can't solve

Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default
(import olJf from "./dist/js/oljf.js";)

My source file

```js
//oljf.js
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';

export default function olJf () {
    new Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new TileLayer({
                source: new OSM(),
            }),
        ],
        view: new View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2,
        }),
    })
};
```

I compile it with vitejs and I import it in my alpine component

```js
//compiled file
import olJf from "./dist/js/oljf.js";

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

    Alpine.data('map', () => ({
            latitude: false,
            longitude: false,
            isLoading: false,
            init() {
                console.log(`map for ${this.latitude}`);
                console.log(window.oljf)
                const mapdiv = document.getElementById('openmap_offre')
                olJf()
            }
        })
    )
})
```

And  I call alpine

```html
<head>
    <script type="module" src="https://xxx.be/wp-content/themes/visittail/assets/js/map.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="openmap_offre" class="mt-3" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" x-data="map" x-init="initMap">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you try to put brackets `{}` around your imports, e.g. `import { Map } from 'ol/Map.js';`?

Comment: i guess you mean here i guess you mean here : import olJf from "./dist/js/oljf.js";

import {Map} from 'ol/Map.js'; is not functional

Comment: I have found the problem my compiled file ./dist/js/oljf.js is empty...

```js
rollupOptions: {
//vite.config.js
            input: {
                appOl: 'src/ol.js',
            },
```